# Backend Theme Error in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10

Anyone ever encourtered this problem 'Uncaught Error: QWeb2: Template 'theme-switcher' not found' on odoo backend theme

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqoEo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Odoo apps](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/themes/browse?order=Relevance&price=Free&series=10.0) and download a theme of your choice